# Perl DBD::SQLAnywhere hangs when running stored procedure

Tags: perl, sqlanywhere

we have an old legacy application running on SQL Anywhere 11. When moving to new software we are first doing a data validation on the legacy system. 
I am using perl to automate this procedure.

It is done by first adding a stored procedure to the database and then executing it and lastly selecting the results from a table.

Now 
Creating the SP using the perl code - OK
Executing the SP using the perl code - NOK
Runnoing the SP in a sql editor and then fetching the result using the perl code - OK

When I try to execute the SP from the perl code the script simply hangs.

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use DBI;
use File::Slurp;
use Data::Dumper;

my $dbh;

sub createConnection{
  my $uid = shift;
  my $pwd = shift;

  my $conn = DBI->connect("DBI:SQLAnywhere:ENG=ENG_NAME",
          "UID=$uid;PWD=$pwd;DBN=dbn;LINKS=tcpip(host=IP;port=port)") or die "Cannot connect to database: $DBI::errstr\n";

  return $conn;
}

sub createProcedure{
    my $procedure = read_file('data_check.sql', binmode => ':utf8');

    $dbh->do($procedure);
}

sub executeProcedure{
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare('CALL prDataCheck(?,?,?);');
    $sth->bind_param(1, '2014-01-14');
    $sth->bind_param(2, 'FSK');
    $sth->bind_param(3, 'Y');
    $sth->execute();

}

sub getResult{
     my $sth = $dbh->prepare('select * from result_table;');
     $sth->execute();
    my $response = $sth->fetchrow_hashref();
    print Dumper $response . "\n";

}


$dbh = createConnection("xxx", "yyy");

createProcedure();
executeProcedure();
getResult();





END{
  $dbh->disconnect;
}
  exit(0);
```

I have tried to execute the SP in various ways:

First Attempt

```
$dbh->do("CALL prDataCheck('2014-01-14','FSK','Y');")
```

Second attempt

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('CALL prDataCheck(?,?,?);');
$sth->bind_param(1, '2014-01-14');
$sth->bind_param(2, 'FSK');
$sth->bind_param(3, 'Y');
$sth->execute();
```

I have tried setting DBI->trace(3) when executing the script:
But not getting much

```
Executing Procedure ..
Go ..
    -> prepare for DBD::SQLAnywhere::db (DBI::db=HASH(0x28042c8)~0x2804208 'call prDataCheck(?,?,?);') thr#2342010
scanned 3 distinct placeholders
    <- prepare= ( DBI::st=HASH(0x2804550) ) [1 items] at dataCheck.pl line 29 via  at dataCheck.pl line 59
executing
    -> execute for DBD::SQLAnywhere::st (DBI::st=HASH(0x2804550)~0x2804268 '2014-01-13' 'FSK' 'Y') thr#2342010
         bind :p1 <== '2014-01-14' (type 0)
Binding input hostvar ':p1' to ordinal 1
         bind :p2 <== 'FSK' (type 0)
Binding input hostvar ':p2' to ordinal 2
         bind :p3 <== 'Y' (type 0)
Binding input hostvar ':p3' to ordinal 3
```

The behavior is the same whichever method I use for executing.

I have also tried using strace when running the scripts but the output just doesn't say much. 
It just seems to be waiting..

```
semop(4816896, {{0, -1, SEM_UNDO}}, 1)  = 0
```

Could someone please shed some light on this for me?
I am kinda stuck ..
I have tried compiling DBD::SQLAnywhere against the SDK found in both sqlanywhere11 and sqlanywhere16.

Kr
Marcus

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to commit your changes. I guess it's a transaction problem.